# Fade with jQuery UI Tabs

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

I have a question with jQuery UI. I am developing a system and you need to create an unknown number of tabs. For this I created it:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("ul.tabs").tabs("> .content");
});
```

The question is that I wanted it to fade function. Try to put several entries found on the Internet, such as {fxFade: true}, but none works.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks and sorry my english.

Comment: How do you want it to fade? on click? on hover?

Answer (score 6):

I think you just need to add the [fx option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#options) to the parameter.

I think this might work for you:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery("ul.tabs").tabs({
        fx: { 
            opacity: 'toggle' 
        }
    });
});
```

Also, I'm not sure what your `> .content` is there for, I don't think jqueryUI tabs is using that argument.

Comment: Using > .content is precisely why I do not know how many users will add tabs (gets in database)

Comment: try starting from this http://jsfiddle.net/partkyle/mMV77/ - You can ignore the css - I just took that from the jquery ui website.